# What would be the influence of nearby planets on a Dyson sphere or Dyson swarm?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, solar-power

Considering orbital mechanics, I would like to ask what would be the effect of nearby planets such as the Earth or Jupiter on a Dyson sphere. A Dyson sphere is not realistic because of the tremendous forces and  instability of the structure. So maybe the same question could be asked for a [Dyson swarm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere#Dyson_swarm).

There is a related question [What would keep Dyson Swarm reflectors in place?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17923/what-would-keep-dyson-swarm-reflectors-in-place) about the effect of the Sun's radiative pressure. Also a [2020 review article on Dyson spheres](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.16734) by [Jason Wright](https://sites.psu.edu/astrowright/jason-t-wright-assistant-professor-of-astronomy-and-astrophysics/) provides insights into the question of optimal size of a Dyson sphere.